# Vertical split with different row views

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with about 400 rows. I have a quick-review table with a bunch of `countif` cells that update based on the data in the rows. The table is in columns `K-O` while the actual data is on columns `A-H`.

I want to review this review data (which goes from rows 2 to 18) while working further down in the document. I can split horizontally, but then I need my top 18 rows to be dedicated to the review table. That's a little wasteful. I can split vertically, but I only get one scroll-bar, so I can't look down further in my spreadsheet.

Is there a way I can vertically split where one can be on row 2ish and the other view can be on row 200ish? If I can't, is there some other way I can have a quick view of this data?

So far, the only way I've managed to do it is by spawning a new window, and re-sizing them. This seems a little more cumbersome than I'd prefer, and I'm still looking for a better way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

A few possible ways to do this:

- Put the quick review table in a separate workbook referring back to the data workbook, and use Windows' own window management features (you do have dual monitors, right?) to view both workbooks simultaneously.
- Structure your data and your quick review table so that **all columns of a certain range of rows**, or alternatively, **all rows of a certain range of columns** are dedicated exclusively to the table. Then you can easily partition off the work by using Freeze Rows. The easiest way to do this would be to put the review table starting at row 1, column A, and assuming it fits on one page with room to spare, you can just start the data immediately below it, and freeze the rows for the review table.
- Use separate worksheets within the same workbook. Similar to the separate workbooks except that internal windows in an Excel MDI application don't have the same robust auto window resizing management features that Windows 7 has, so it's easier (for viewing purposes) to use separate workbooks so that you get separate top level windows.

I agree that "vertical panes with separate scrollbars and row indexes" would be nice, but I don't think that exists...

Comment: I do not have dual monitors on my laptop. I do at my workstation, but not while traveling, so no-go on option 1. For option 2, my review table is 17 rows long, with potential to grow. I don't want to waste the top 17 rows of my screen with my review table. As for option 3, I could certainly link two worksheets together; I don't see an option to view both worksheets simultaneously.